# I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I am recieving error message when trying to update software. Can i fix this?

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-center

I am receiving this message when trying to update:-
failed to fetch http://gb.archive.abuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/software-center_5.2.2.1_all.deb 404 not found

My Internet connection is good and stable but this is preventing my updates from downloading and I would like some information which may help me resolve this problem.

Thank you.

p.s. I'm new to using linux OS:)

Comment: I might have been a little hasty in writing this question.  Although I have changed nothing the updates have downloaded now, the number of updated had increased significantly from 27 to 56 so maybe this had something to do with it.

Comment: I had the same problem. Did a `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` on the command line -- all fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a couple of things.

**Sources not updated**

Although Ubuntu's desktop will do it for you occasionally, you often need to update your sources before you can install packages, to make sure your package manager gets any recent changes to the available packages.

You do this with the "Check" button in the update manager, or with `sudo apt-get update` on the command-line.

**Temporary problem with mirror**

Occasionally, depending on the mirror you are using, there can be temporary problems where the mirror goes down temporarily or has other issues.

You will often find that if you try the same thing again later, the problems have resolved.  Or, if it is something important, try a different mirror.