# Errors when installing g++

Tags: apt, g++

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing here. I'm trying to install g++ so I can run c++ code and its not working at all.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

[image: errors]

Comment: Did you run sudo apt update before trying the install?  Looks like you lost internet connectivity, try a ping on the 91.189.91.82 address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I am recieving error message when trying to update software. Can i fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146069/im-running-ubuntu-12-04-lts-and-i-am-recieving-error-message-when-trying-to-upd) and [Apt-get failed to fetch from Ubuntu server with error code 404](https://askubuntu.com/q/118191/)

Comment: @karel I am not sure. the error code 404 one looks similar, but they're talking about proxies and stuff and I honestly have no clue what any of that means or how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt-get failed to fetch from Ubuntu server with error code 404](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118191/apt-get-failed-to-fetch-from-ubuntu-server-with-error-code-404)